# How to make python ignore a blank cell and continue downloading images from the next cell

Tags: pandas, python-requests, shutil

when iterating through the cell
if a blank cell comes up, and error pops up and stop download. is there any  exception or steps to ignore a blank cell?

```
for j in u.iteritems():
       
        file_name = str(i)+".jpeg"
        res = requests.get(u[0], stream = True)

        if res.status_code == 200:
            with open(file_name,'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(res.raw, f) 
            print('Image sucessfully Downloaded: ',file_name)
        else:
            print('Image Couldn\'t be retrieved')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a try: ..., except: continue block (or try:..., except: pass block)
something like this:

```
for j in u.iteritems():
    try:
       file_name = str(j)+".jpeg"
       res = requests.get(u[0], stream = True)

       if res.status_code == 200:
           with open(file_name,'wb') as f:
              shutil.copyfileobj(res.raw, f) 
           print('Image sucessfully Downloaded: ',file_name)
       else:
           print('Image Couldn\'t be retrieved')
    except:
       continue
```

Comment: i do not know how to add an exception here